# Why is this JS error thrown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, rendering

Executing this following piece of code:

```
function Events (props){
  const clickHandler = console.log;

  return (<button onClick={clickHandler}> Make an event </button>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<Events />, mountNode);
```

I get this error: `Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)`

The code is from a pluralsight ReactJS course and when the guy who is presenting the course executes the code, he gets the event triggering object printed in the console, while I get this error.

Comment: Is this the only code you're running? Which version of React are you using?

Comment: yes, this is the only code I'm running and I am running the code at `https://jscomplete.com/repl`

Comment: I don't think the error is generated by React. Works on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtenmbp8/)

Comment: yes, it works on JSFiddle. The course code snippet is executed in JSFiddle. But still, why the error when running in JSComplete? I tried @Tholle's code in JSComplete and I get the same error.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the way JSComplete compiles and runs the code. Have you tried it locally?

Comment: @Skyp89 It's most likely due to jscomplete trying to `JSON.stringify` what it logs to the console. It will work in other environments that don't do that. `event.persist()` is still needed when the event will be used asynchronously, and `console.log` might be asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is most likely due to jscomplete trying to `JSON.stringify` what it logs to the console. A React `SyntheticEvent` has a circular structure, which will give rise to your error when using `JSON.stringify` on it.

It might work in other environments, but `console.log` might also be asynchronous. This problem is brought up in the [documentation about `SynthenticEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling):

> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you
>   should call `event.persist()` on the event, which will remove the
>   synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be
>   retained by user code.

So if you plan on using the event asynchronously, the following will work:

```
function Events (props){
  const clickHandler = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    console.log(event);
  };

  return (<button onClick={clickHandler}> Make an event </button>);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would be a problem in OP's code he's not referencing the event object in any async code.

Comment: @AndreiNemes `console.log` can be asynchronous depending on the [implementation in the particular environment used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync).